# In a distributed network such as Bitcoin, how do a node find its peers after initial connection?

Tags: p2p, blockchain

Suppose that the client keeps a hardcoded table of some known, famous nodes in order to start the connection with the network. When that node initially connects to the entry point, it must then proceed to find its own peers. How is that done?

The node obviously can't just ask the initial nodes for their neighbors.

Comment: "The node obviously can't just ask the initial nodes for their neighbors." - it can't? that's not obvious to me.

Comment: @the8472 woops, what I mean is, that can't be "only it", because otherwise you'd always get the same nodes (the ones close to the initial peers), so there must be some additional rebalancing step. I'm in particular wondering if something complex such as kademlia is required/used, or if we could have it as simple as randomly asking nodes neighbors and then neighbors neighbors for a while. Would that, for example, make the overall network structure somehow defective? Things like that is what is puzzling me.

Answer (score 4):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery explains the process pretty well.

The gist is:

- A central service to identify self's public IP address.
- Hardcoded IRC channel, DNS domains or IP addresses to discover initial nodes.
- Followed by each node regularly sharing their peers using specific advertisement messages.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm in particular wondering if something complex such as kademlia is required/used, or if we could have it as simple as randomly asking nodes neighbors and then neighbors neighbors for a while.

Both exist, the commonly used terms are structured and unstructured overlay network. The latter usually try to be a small world network.

Whether a simple network is sufficient depends on what you want to do with it. They generally work well enough for simply propagating updates to everyone or forming separate networks for each topic of interest. More complex things like address-based lookups on the other hand will benefit from structued overlays like kademlia.